# Cordova Webview Image Cache on Android and iOS, when is it cleared?

Tags: cordova

I have a basic Cordova app (Cordova Version 6.0.0, Cordova Android Platform - 5.1.1, Cordova iOS Platform - 4.0.0) which displays images from a web server in a HTML img tag as shown below -

```
<img src="http://abcd.com/images/1.png" />
```

The default cordova webview caches images - that is - even when the device is OFFLINE and the app is closed and relaunched the previously loaded images are displayed.

I want to know when exactly is this image cache cleared or under what circumstances the image cache is cleared on android and iOS devices?

Also is there a memory size limit for this WebView Cache?

Comment: I don't think you can count on this cache. Every platform and version can handle it a bit differently. For example iOS will clear cache (and even local storage) every time if phone is running low on memory.